# R calls mGENOVA-an external Program

Tags: r, call, system, external

Recently I have been trying to use R to call a .exe program named [mGenov](https://education.uiowa.edu/centers/center-advanced-studies-measurement-and-assessment/computer-programs)  It's command line program. I have some screenshots to help me explain this (I use Windows 10).

Supposedly, it works this way:

1. double click on mGenova,
2. type card.txt
3. hit "enter" the cmd window will close

I have tried a lot; basically they can invoke the program, but pass the command about typing card.txt in the command

```
shell(cmd="D:\\mgenova\\mGENOVA\\card.txt", shell="D:\\mgenova\\mGENOVA\\mGENOVA.exe",intern=F)
```

## OR

```
system("\"D:\\mgenova\\mGENOVA\\mGENOVA.exe\" \"D:\\mgenova\\mGENOVA\\card.txt\""
,show.output.on.console=TRUE,invisible=T,intern=T)
```

And I always got this

```
[1] "Input the filename containing the control cards." ""                                                 ""                                                 "*** Control cards file is empty"                 
attr(,"status")
[1] 1
Warning message:
running command '"D:\mgenova\mGENOVA\mGENOVA.exe" "D:\mgenova\mGENOVA\card.txt"' had status 1
```

How can I get it run on it? Thanks for helping!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a batchfile (let's name it batch.bat) on Windows with the content

```
cd /D D:\mgenova\mGENOVA\
mGENOVA.exe < card.txt
```

All necessary input for GENOVA must be provided by the file card.txt.

Then in R run the command

```
system("batch.bat")
```